# how to create session and how to fetch data from mysql database in jsp using session?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to create session on login page and want to fetch data from mysql database using the session created in jsp. And want to show this created session on home page.

Comment: this question is too broad, please describe more your context and what you did so far

Comment: fetch data from mysql database using the session ?

Comment: you can create a session and store what you got from database is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
        //get data from the database and assign them to 
        //user name and password

        String userName = "name from database";
        String password = "123";

        //adding values to a session
        session.setAttribute("user",userName);
        session.setAttribute("pass",password);


       %>

       ////getting values from session 
       userName : <%=session.getAttribute("user") %>
       password : <%=session.getAttribute("pass") %>
```

this is very simple example on using session object in your jsp. try this to get an idea about sessions.